# Arista ceos dnsmasq

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, kubernetes, router, dnsmasq

I'm using Arista cEOS 4.29.2F and I'm trying to use the dns proxy that this device allow.
However, when I do systemctl status dnsmasq on the Arista's bash, its output is:

> ● dnsmasq.service - SYSV: This script starts your DNS caching server
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/dnsmasq; generated)    Active: failed
> (Result: protocol) since Fri 2023-05-05 08:10:58 UTC; 1min 44s ago
> Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 26511 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/dnsmasq start (code=exited,
> status=0/SUCCESS)
> CPU: 9ms
>
> May 05 08:10:58 helmchartrepo-router-0016833632-f54cb75f4-6phqx
> dnsmasq[26511]: Starting dnsmasq:

Moreover, when I do systemctl restart dnsmasq it appears the following output:

> Job for dnsmasq.service failed because the service did not take the
> steps required by its unit configuration. See "systemctl status
> dnsmasq.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.